# Visual Studio c++ warnings only from project directory

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2019, suppress-warnings

Is it possible to configure a c++ project to only show compiler warnings from files in my project directory?

I am interested in first cleaning warnings from my code, and then if time allows from other includes which generate tons of warnings.

Comment: No.  Click the "File" column header to sort the error list by file.

Comment: @HansPassant Great, not only that I can sort, I can then create filter to include only files that I want. Almost exactly what i need. Thx.

Comment: @HansPassant If you post an answer with this this I will accept it in few days if no one provides some crazy msbuild switch that be used in .vcxproj. Although this way now looks cleaner to me, not sure if suppressing warnings in such way in .vcxproj is a good idea ;)